# Yes/No question statistics

Tags: binary-data, proportion

I'm very new to statistics and am trying to figure it all out! I have a number of yes / no questions answered from a survey. (a) I want to see if, in each question, there is a statistical significance to either the yes or no being greater (for example, out of 698 respondents, 569 said yes, 129 said no, what does this tell me??) (b) I want to see if there is a co-relation between saying yes to question 1 and yes to question 2, etc.

Comment: Maybe you could explain us how you have analyzed these questions descriptively?

Answer (score 7):

To answer (a), I would suggest a $z$-test for proportions.  Your null hypothesis should be $H_0: p_Y=0.5$ against the alternative $H_A:p_Y\neq 0.5$, where $p_Y$ is the proportion of people who answered "Yes."

To answer (b), I would suggest using a two-way table to display your data, then executing a chi-squared test with null $H_0:$ no association exists between question $i$ and question $j$ against the alternative $H_A:$ an association exists between question $i$ and question $j$. In this case, you can detect whether or not an association exists between the answer to question 1 and the answer to question 2.  You can repeat this for each pair of questions that you deem appropriate.

Comment: +1 for good suggestions. But to clarify (for the OP), $p_Y$ is a parameter, i.e. something like the "true proportion of all members of the population who *would* answer yes". The proportion of people (in the sample) who answered "yes" is a statistic, usually denoted $\hat p_y$ (or simply $\bar{x}$ since these are Bernoulli trials).